# Прописная или строчная буква при разрыве прямой речи и многоточии?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, прописная-строчная, прямая-речь, многоточие

Скажите, если прямая речь разрывается (прерывается), а потом возобновляется как часть предыдущего предложения, следует начинать её с прописной либо строчной буквы?
Многоточия в таком случае указывают на места разрыва. Где это правило найти?

*— Человек пять-шесть, через минуту — уже **около...**

Опять раздался грохот, но тут же стих.

— **...дюжины**. В общем, через час там уже их было больше сотни.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все пунктуационные нюансы объять правилами невозможно, но предполагаю, что для оформления указанной текстовой конструкции **дозволительно** ориентироваться вот на это:

> **4.** Если одна реплика «разрывается» другой, а затем следует продолжение первой реплики, то после первой ее части и перед началом второй ставится многоточие:
> *— Я **просил...**
>
> — Ничего вы не просили.
>
> — **...хотя** бы минуту внимания.*

Разорванная реплика при продолжении начинается многоточием, слово пишется со **строчной** буквы — то есть ваши «...дюжины» считаю верными.
Нашелся  и подходящий пример (Леонид Сапожников. Митя Метелкин в Стране Синих роз):

> — Да куда же он запропастился?! — воскликнул капитан.
> — Наверно, упал в воду, — печальным голосом проговорил робот. — Наверно, он упал в воду и... и... **и...**
> Какое-то страшное слово застряло у Кибрика в горле. Медиан хлопнул робота по спине, чтобы ему было легче сказать.
> — **...и утонул**, — договорил робот, снимая с головы бескозырку. Из его зеленых глаз, как слезы, закапало машинное масло.

[Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160) (Розенталь)